# Rails 4 SQL Join Code

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm building a marketplace app. I have a Listing model (users list items to sell) and a User model. In the listing model, I have a userid column. And in the User model, I have a name field. In my listing show page, I want to display something like the below:

```
"Sold by #{@listing.user.name}"
```

But the join doesn't work in retrieving the name from the user table. If I change it to `listing.userid` then it works but I want to display the users name.

my user model has `has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy`

My listings model has `belongs_to :user`.

How can I display the user's name on the listing show page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have a column called `userid` instead of `user_id` then you have something very slightly different to what Rails expects... which is why Rails isn't finding it for you automatically.

Your best bet is to rename the column (using a migration) to `user_id` to take advantage of the Rails default behaviour. Trust me - it's worth the effort up front if you can do this.

If for some odd reason you can't (serious business constraints), then there are ways of telling rails that you are using a non-standard foreign-key... but lets not get to that unless you have to.

Comment: Yes, it is userid. I can change it but since I'm using it already in multiple pieces of code, I'd prefer not to change it. What is the way of telling rails that I have a nonstandard foreign key?

Comment: I looked it up and added the option to my listing model `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "userid"` and it works now. Any downside to doing this that I should be aware of?

Comment: Seriously, you will save yourself much more hassle in the long run if you put in the effort to change it now... than if you leave it in there as legacy code... you can just do a search+replace now. The downside is continual maintenance and mental overhead (having to remember, every time you use it, that it's non-standard). This counts as technical debt... and I suggest you pay the up-front cost rather than wearing the interest forever.